# How to force update MutableStateFlow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a daily challenge screen but my state doesn't update when the date change while having the app open (ie: from 07/11/2022 23:59 to 08/11/2022 00:00)

```kotlin
data class MyObject(val startDate: Date, val lastVote: List<Date> = emptyList()) {
    fun isChallengeDone(): Boolean {
        return Calendar.getInstance().time >= startDate
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class DailyChallengeViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val _currentDay = MutableStateFlow(Calendar.getInstance())
        
    private val _myObject = MutableStateFlow(MyObject(
            Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                set(Calendar.DATE, 8)
                set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                set(Calendar.MINUTE , 0)
                set(Calendar.SECOND , 0)
                set(Calendar.MILLISECOND , 0)
            }.time
        ))
    val myObject = _myObject.asStateFlow()

    init {
        _myObject.combine(_currentDay) { obj, _ ->
            _myObject.value = obj
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
    }

    fun updateDate() {
        _currentDay.value = Calendar.getInstance()
    }
}

@Composable
fun DailyChallengeScreen(viewModel: DailyChallengeViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(context) {
        val receiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                viewModel.updateDate()
            }
        }
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED))
        onDispose {
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
    }
    val myObject by viewModel.myObject.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    DailyChallengeContent(myObject)
}

@Composable
fun DailyChallengeContent(myObject: MyObject) {
    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)) {
        Text("${Calendar.getInstance().time} >= ${myObject.startDate}")
        Text(myObject.isChallengeDone().toString())
    }
}
```

I know `_myObject.combine(_currentDay) { obj, _ ->_myObject.value = obj }` doesn't update because `_myObject.value` is atomically equal to `obj`. What can be done to update my composable when the date change ?

Comment: Why do you need _currentDay flow? Just to track and update current date? Why not update _myObject directly in the updateDate() function? BTW the result of **_myObject.combine(_currentDay) {...** is never used because it is not assigned to anything and therefore is not observed.

Comment: I've tried to do update in `updateDate()` with `_myObject.value = _myObject.value` as `_myObject` doesn't change between dates but it didn't update my Composable. For `combine` you're right I forgot the `launchIn`, I've updated it

Comment: _myObject.value = _myObject.value is not an update since the value has not changed. And to use the result of **combine** you should assign it to some new flow and observe this new flow, like **myCombinedObject = _myObject.combine(_currentDay) { obj, _ -> ...** and in UI: **val myObject by viewModel.myCombinedObject.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()**

Comment: It didn't do the trick, my composable still doesn't update

Comment: Use of Date, Calendar and other `java.util` date classes is highly discouraged. The `java.time` classes are lot more robust and also are a better choice for StateFlows and State because they are immutable. Regarding your specific question, I'm not sure of the best way to update state on a schedule and still be able to handle app suspension without getting out of sync.

Comment: thanks for the time input but the real issue is the `MutableStateFlow` not updating

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way but it does work.

```kotlin
data class MyObject(val startDate: Date, val lastVote: List<Date> = emptyList()) {
    fun isChallengeDone(): Boolean {
        return Calendar.getInstance().time >= startDate
    }
}

@HiltViewModel
class DailyChallengeViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _myObject = MutableStateFlow(MyObject(
            Calendar.getInstance().apply {
                set(Calendar.DATE, 8)
                set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                set(Calendar.MINUTE , 0)
                set(Calendar.SECOND , 0)
                set(Calendar.MILLISECOND , 0)
            }.time
        ))
    val myObject = _myObject.asStateFlow()
}

@Composable
fun DailyChallengeScreen(viewModel: DailyChallengeViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val myObject by viewModel.myObject.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    DailyChallengeContent(myObject)
}

@Composable
fun DailyChallengeContent(myObject: MyObject) {
    var currentDate by remember { mutableStateOf(Calendar.getInstance().time) }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(context) {
        val receiver = object: BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().time
            }
        }
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED))
        onDispose {
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
    }

    val isChallengeDone by remember(currentDate, myObject) {
        mutableStateOf(myObject.isChallengeDone())
    }
    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)) {
        Text("${Calendar.getInstance().time} >= ${myObject.startDate}")
        Text(isChallengeDone.toString())
    }
}
```